# How to how that $x \operatorname{cosech}(x) $ is Schwartz function?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

We know $f (x)$ is in Schwartz  space if for given  $ m, k $ non negative integers  the supremum of $ \left|x^{m  }  f^{(k)}(x) \right| $ over  the real numbers is finite.
How to show that $x \operatorname{cosech}(x) $ is in the Schwartz  space? I proved this supremum is finite for initial particular values of $m ,k$ but don't know how to proceed in general case. Please help

Comment: Show by induction that $f^{(k)}$ is a finite sum of terms of the form $$\frac{P(x)Q(\sinh x, \cosh x)}{\sinh^n x},$$ where $P,Q$ are polynomials, and $n > \deg Q$. Then use $p(x)e^{-\lvert x\rvert} \to 0$ as $\lvert x\rvert \to \infty$ for all polynomials $p$.

Answer (score 1):

Is complex analysis allowed? If so, you may exploit the representation:
$$ \frac{x}{\sinh x} = 1+\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{2x^2 (-1)^n}{x^2+n^2 \pi^2} $$
that comes from a Weierstrass product. As an alternative, you may prove that
$$ \mathcal{L}\left(\frac{x}{\sinh x}\right) = \frac{1}{2}\psi'\left(\frac{s+1}{2}\right)$$
and both the given identities easily lead to $\frac{x}{\sinh x}\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$. 
Also, the Fourier transform of $\frac{x}{\sinh x}$ behaves like $\frac{1}{\cosh(x)^2}$, and it is probably easier to check that $\frac{1}{\cosh(x)^2}=\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\log\cosh(x)\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$.